# add alt for images in a while statement

Tags: php, image, alt

Can anyone help please?
This is my code.I want to add  an alt option for images but everything I try is throwing errors.
I have tried studying the php handbook and have tried copying code from other questions but so far no luck.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "logosewe_5";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "logosewe_5";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mk2";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mk2 WHERE brand='2786'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<img src='$row['ming']'>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: _What errors_ is it throwing?

Answer (score 1):

You have a [string concatenation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) problem :

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['ming'] . '">';
```

Will output : `<img src="myimage.jpg">`.

To add a `alt` attribute, you could do :

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['ming'] . '" alt="' . $row['name'] . '">';
```

Will output something like

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="image name">
```

Answer (score 1):

**change your code like this:**

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "logosewe_5";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "logosewe_5";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mk2"
    ;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mk2 WHERE brand='2786'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<img src="'.$row['ming'].'" alt="'.$altText.'">'; //change here
     }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you did not have an alt attribute in your echo statement and the second was your concatenation was a little off with misplaced quotes.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<img src=' . $row['ming'] .  'alt="Your alt message">';
}
```